# state machine for serial protocol

Tags: c, serial-port, uart, state-machine

i am writing a state machine in c for a serial protocol. My packet format looks like this.

delim0  interface  command_H  command_L  length_H  length_l  payload  checksum  delim1

edit:my question is how to write a c code for computing the payload and checksum using this state machine.

i am new to this topic and if i have made any simple mistakes please excuse me.

```
switch (dev_int_state) {
          case UART_INT_STATE_IDLE:
                if (c == '<') {         // Delim0 = 0x3C

                dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_INTERFACE;
  }
  break;
          case UART_INT_STATE_INTERFACE:
               if (c == 0x00) {         //Generic Commands = 0x00

               dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_REQ_INTERFACE_SUPPORTED;
  }
  break;
           case UART_INT_STATE_REQ_INTERFACE_SUPPORTED:
                if (c == 0x00) {        // REQ_INTERFACE_SUPPORTED = 0x00

               dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_GET_PROTOCOLHH;
  }
  break;
           case UART_INT_STATE_GET_PROTOCOLHH:
                if (c == 0x00) {          // GET_PROTOCOL = 0x00

               dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_GET_PROTOCOLHL;
  }
 break;
           case UART_INT_STATE_GET_PROTOCOLHL:
                if (c == 0x0B) {           // GET_PROTOCOL_RESPONSE = 0x000B

               dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_LENGTHH;
  }
 break;
          case UART_INT_STATE_LENGTHH:
               if (c ==0x04) {

          dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_LENGTHL;          // LENGHT = 4 bytes
  }
 break;
          case UART_INT_STATE_LENGTHL:
          if (c == 0x00) {



          dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_PAYLOAD;
  }
 break;
          case UART_INT_STATE_PAYLOAD:


                       {        //--- i want to store the payload in this state

                                      }

          case UART_INT_STATE_CHECKSUM:

{
              size = 0;
              for (unsigned i = 0; i< headerLength-1; i++) { /* i have computed checksum but not sure about it */
                  size += headerBuffer[i];
              }

              dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_DELIM1;
}
 break;

               dev_int_state = UART_INT_STATE_DELIM1;
 }
 break;
         case UART_INT_STATE_DELIM1:
              if (c == '>') {





      }
       break;
  default:
       break;
}
```

Comment: *"my question is how to compute the payload and checksum using this state machine."* What do you mean by this? Question has to be precise, or it won't be answerable. Please [edit], and have only one *clear* question.

Comment: You'd calculate payload and checksum as specified for the given protocol. How do you expect some random people on the internet to be able to tell _you_ how _your_ specific, custom-made UART protocol is built?

Comment: Note: your states all have only one *outgoing* state. I think you'll need to fall back to the initial state now and then (on error) to resynchronize.

Comment: .. and add more states to handle the 4-byte length field and checksum, and a couple to handle the variable-length payload, (init and subsequent).  You don't HAVE to change state for every byte - the variable-length payload state does not need a state for each byte!

Comment: @Lundin i have calculated payload and checksum for my UART protocol but i am not sure how to write a syntax for it. So i wanted to know the syntax for computing payload and checksum using state machines.

Comment: What does the state machine even have to do with anything? It is just a way of selecting which code that gets sorted - beyond that it is completely dumb. If you know the algorithms, simply code them and then put them in a state machine or wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep saving the received character `c` into a buffer and increment the index
   `buffer[index++] = c;`
2. Once you reach the  `case UART_INT_STATE_CHECKSUM:`
   If you have a simple `sum-of-sums` checksum, then add all the bytes in the buffer (except the checksum byte). Then compare it with the checksum byte received. It really depends upon what kind of checksum your protocol has.

Note: You are using `c` as 1-byte sometimes and 2-bytes sometimes. If c is a character, then it will be 1-byte always. May be easier if you capture the whole packet first, then cast it to a structure of your protocol type and check the appropriate values.

For example:

```
typedef struct uart_protocol_t
{
    uint8_t delim0;
    uint8_t interface;
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t command_H;
            uint8_t command_L;
        }cmd_bytes;
        uint16_t command;
    }cmd_union;
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t length_H;
            uint8_t length_L;
        }len_bytes;
        uint16_t length;
    }len_union;
    uint8_t payload;
    uint8_t checksum;
    uint8_t delim1;
}uart_protocol_t;
```

Then cast it

```
uart_protocol_t *p_proto = (uart_protocol_t *)buffer;
```

Comment: Unions like these is usually not a good idea, since they depend on the endianess of the CPU rather than the endianess of the data protocol. Also please note that this struct may introduce padding at any point inside the struct.

Comment: `uart_protocol_t *p_proto = (uart_protocol_t *)buffer;` This code will probably not work on many real-world processors at all, because of the mentioned padding/alignment concerns. Most likely you have to write serialize/de-serialize routines instead.